# zumero: Xamarin Android. How to get a Android.Database.ICursor from a SQLiteConnection?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, zumero

Is there any way of how to get a Android.Database.ICursor or a Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteCursor from a Zumero_SQLite_Android.System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection or SQLiteCommand to be used in a CursorAdapter or a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption here that you're using the [Zumero cloud service](http://zumero.com/dev-center/cloud/), as opposed to [Zumero for SQL Server](http://zumero.com/dev-center/zss/).  The answer is slightly different for the two products (and much simpler in Zumero for SQL Server).

Also, what will be consuming the cursor?  If your goal is to use the cursor to drive a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you will probably be happier if you just create a subclass of `BaseAdapter` and ignore cursors altogether. Your base adapter would use the  `Zumero_SQLite_Android.System.Data.SQLite` classes to get the data needed to populate the views in GetView.

As for getting a `ICursor`, since all SQLite calls on Android for the cloud service need to go through a Zumero-bundled SQLite provider, getting a cursor will be a bit tricky. You can't just use the `Android.Database.Sqlite` classes.  If you really need an `ICursor, I would try binding the Zumero Android Java libraries as described here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/

and then calling the `com.zumero.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` methods to get a Cursor.